# Split a full name using PHP list or explode function

Tags: php, string, explode

I am trying to split a name that I pull from a webpage using simple HTML DOM and the list and explode functions aren't doing the trick. All I want to do is take a name {firstname middle(optional) lastname} and split them. The middle name only shows up on some names and it would be a bonus if I could handle that.

Here's the code:

```
    <?php

    $data = new simple_html_dom();  
    $data->load_file("http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=861228");
    $profName= $data->find("//*[@id=profName]", 0);
    $profName = strip_tags($profName);
    echo "Full Name: " . $profName = trim($profName);
    list($first, $last) = explode(' ', "$profName ");
    echo "first name: " .  $first;
    echo "last name: " . $last;
?>
```

My output reads:

```
Full Name: Jennifer Aaker
firstname: Jennifer Aaker
lastname:
```

Comment: What's with the `"$profName "`? Why the space?

Comment: I meant to remove that since I thought the string delimiter wasn't detecting the whitespace correctly so I added one myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with:

```
list($first, $last) = explode("&nbsp;", $profName);
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully. Thank you! I was reading the output on the browser and wasn't aware of the sneaky &nbsp;

Comment: Now I need to work on the function to handle that optional middle name

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that should do the trick.

```
function first_last($s) {
    /* assume first name is followed by a whitespace character. take everything after for last. middle initial will be returned as part of last. */
    $pos = strpos($s,' ');
    if ($pos == FALSE) { // if space is not found... call if first name
        return array($s,''); 
    }
    $first = substr($s, 0 , $pos);
    $last = substr($s,$pos + 1);    
    return array($first,$last);
}

// test
$s2 = 'john stewart';
list($first,$last) = first_last($s2);
```